# Lua: Why does my function call have a nil error?

Tags: arrays, function, module, lua, null

In my code, I have a Script and two ModuleScripts. In one of the ModuleScripts, I created a table called storageArray.

```
local module2 = {}

module2.storageArray = {}

return module2
```

In the other ModuleScript, I created a function called printInfo.

```
local module2 = require(game.ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("storageModule")) -- calls storageModule ModuleScript

----Variables----
functionArray = {} -- Global Variable

----Game Functions----
functionArray = {
    printInfo = function(info)
        print(info)
    end
}
return functionArray
```

The error I'm running into is that when I call the function printStorageArray, I get the error "attempt to index nil with 'printInfo'". This is my function call in the regular Script:

```
----Game Events----
local module = require(game.ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("Functions")) -- calls Functions ModuleScript
local module2 = require(game.ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("storageModule")) -- calls storageModule ModuleScript


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player1) -- Gets Username/UserID of user that has joined game
    local name = player1.Name
    print(name .. " has entered the game!") -- Adds userID to storageArray (storageArray holds all users that've joined the game)
    local ID = player1.UserId               -- Activates every time someone joins server                     
    print(ID)
    local storageArray = module.storageArray
    table.insert(module2.storageArray, ID)
    print("ID's: " .. module2.storageArray[1] .. ", ") -- **Test w/ 2 people
    local playerName = player1.Name
end)

print("TEST")

module.functionArray.printInfo(module2.storageArray) -- ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If `functionArray` is a global variable in the module, why do you access it as `module.functionArray` in the main script?

Comment: I’ve already tried that. When I just do functionArray.printInfo, the computer says that it doesn’t know what functionArray is.

Comment: Your module should return a value instead of creating global variables

Comment: It does return the value of functionArray at the end of the module

Comment: Then you should write `module.printInfo` instead of `module.functionArray.printInfo`

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!